# How to clear screen in python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a command to clear the screen in python, with so far no luck. I'm want to make a python drawing program, and I am updating the "canvas" (A series of spaces and pound signs stored in lists) every time a change is made. I have tried both `os.system('clear')` and `call('clear')`, but I've found that instead of clearing the screen, they both just add newlines until all the characters from before the command are not visible. This is unwanted because otherwise the user can just scroll up and look at the previous formats of the "canvas". So, is there a python command that legitimately clears the screen?

This is not a duplicate question. I have looked at the question that someone posted, and all answers still turned up the same: newline characters, but no "real" screen clearing.

Comment: Are you in IPython, terminal/command prompt, or IDLE

Comment: If you want to do some "complicated" stuff try this instead https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: I run my python scripts straight from Geany, so terminal.

Comment: Try this: `print(chr(27) + "[2J")`

Comment: `print(chr(27) + "[2J")` still has the same problem

Comment: @TyStaszak even when typing 'clear' on a terminal, the screen is still scrollable - so python does exact that...

Comment: @coder so there is no non-scrollable clear command?

Comment: @TyStaszak as far as I know there isn't, but there are some ways you can overwrite the previous line (using carriage return `\r`) or maybe a GUI lib that offers that functionality